# Design Pattern for converting Java Data Model to XLS Workbook Sheet

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, architecture, system-design

Basically, I want to convert Java Object Model into two different sheets of an XLS workbook. I have solved this problem so far but I am trying to find better solution in terms of design pattern.

Here is the response Object Model.

```
class Response {
  List<Model1> list;
}

class Model1 {
  String attr1;
  String attr2;
  List<Model2> list;

  @JsonProperty(value="attr1")
  String getAttr1() {..}
}

class Model2 {
  String attr1;
  String attr2;

  @JsonProperty(value="attr1")
  String getAttr1() {..}
}
```

For conversion layer, I created a parent interface with different implementation as below.

```
public interface Converter<T> {
  Sheet convert(T t);
}

public class DataConverter {

   public Workbook getWorkBook(Response res) {
      Sheet model1Sheet = new Model1SheetConverter().convert(res);
      Sheet model2Sheet = new Model2SheetConverter().convert(res);
      return new Workbook().sheets(List.of(model1Sheet, model2Sheet));
   }
}

public class Model1SheetConvert implements Converter<Response> {
   public sheet convert(Response res) {
       I do loop over here for data model 1 and then with some business logic generate sheet.
   }
}

public class Model2SheetConvert implements Converter<Response> {
   public sheet convert(Response res) {
       I do loop over here for each data model 1 then I pass data model 2 and then with some business logic generate sheet.
   }
}
```

Now problem with this approach are:

1. I am iterating two times for data model 1.
2. There will be some dynamic rows for sheet 1 and sheet 2 based on data model 1. I can not handle this part here with this approach.

Can someone please suggest a good design pattern for this approach?
Or, is there is any other way, I can do it differently.

Comment: Your `Converter<T>` effectively is a `Strategy` pattern - varying the algorithm of conversion based on the type of the input. What I don't exactly follow - can a "Model 1 Sheet" (its contents) contain also cell data converted from Model 2 objects (which Model1 contains) ? In other words - is there a content aggregation need here, in a sense that convert(Model2) does not necessarily produce a new Sheet, since data from Model2 may be necessary to convert into an already existing Model 1 sheet ? Or is the relationship between Sheet content and Model1 / Model2 classes strictly one-to-one ?

Comment: Hi @Risto Uibo, Acutally I need to create two sheets, one from Model 1 and other from Model 2. So if Model 1 contains one item in list and two Model 2 items then sheet 1 will have 1 row and sheet 2 will have tow rows.

Answer (score 2):

As the foundation of one possible design, these are the main needs according to my understanding -

- One converter is required for each type (class) of a Model - eg Model1 should have its converter, and Model2 its own. The converter then produces (fills, or writes into) a single workbook `Sheet`. I will further name the converter a `SheetWriter`, and its polymorphic method a `write(M model)` method. That is, accepting a Model of its designated type.
- We need 2 classes - a `Model1Writer` and a `Model2Writer` - each created so, that it holds a single Sheet instance and keeps appending data (i.e., rows) into it. At each call to its `write(M model)` method, keeps returning the same Sheet object. So if we call both's `write(M model)` methods for i.e. 19 `Model1` instances and their 55 "child" `Model2` instances, then we still must end up with exactly two sheets: `Model1` Sheet has all the info for those 19 `Model1` instances (i.e., 19 rows), while `Model2` Sheet has all the info for those 55 `Model2` instance (i.e., 55 rows).
- So, we need to *stream* all the models in the Response - both its models and in turn all their children - and convert (map) them to these unique 2 Sheets using appropriate `SheetWriter` instances (depending on the class of the model).

Considering the above foundation - a following design and its implementation could be our starting solution. It combines a **Factory** pattern with **Strategy**. Factory being the source of concrete SheetWriters (given a concrete model), while Strategy being the concrete SheetWriter eg the writing logic, for its corresponding model class.

[image]

Here is the implementation of ResponseConverter:

```java
public class ResponseConverter {

    private final Writers factory;
    private final Map<Class<? extends WritableModel>, SheetWriter<? extends WritableModel>> writers;

    public ResponseConverter(Writers factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.writers = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Workbook toWorkbook(Response response) {
        Set<Sheet> sheets = streamAllModelsIn(response)
            .map(model -> getWriter(model).write(model))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

        return new Workbook(sheets.toArray(new Sheet[] {}));
    }

    private Stream<WritableModel> streamAllModelsIn(Response response) {
        List<Model1> mainModels = response.getModels();
        Stream<WritableModel> childrenStream = mainModels.stream().flatMap(this::streamChildren);

        return Stream.concat(mainModels.stream(), childrenStream);
    }

    private Stream<? extends WritableModel> streamChildren(Model1 model) {
        return model.getChildren().stream();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <M extends WritableModel> SheetWriter<M> getWriter(M model) {
        if (!writers.containsKey(model.getClass())) {
            writers.put(model.getClass(), factory.writerFor(model));
        }
        return (SheetWriter<M>) writers.get(model.getClass());
    }
}
```

In the above listing, the main key is the private `getWriter(M model)` method. It  uses an internal "cached map" of `writers` to get the correct `SheetWriter` instance corresponding to the current model's class - or, if there is yet no such map entry, uses the `Writers factory` to initialize it - to ask a new instance that is appropriate for the given model.

The second part is the `writers` package's implementation - meaning, the actual factory mechanism + concrete strategies of `SheetWriter` which write your `Model1` and `Model2` instances into their output sheets. This includes the three "public" components (white classes) of the "writers" package that the outside code can use, as well as some "hidden" components (gray classes) which are only used inside the package mechanism and not visible to ResponseHandler or anything else outside. The goal is to be able to add more package-protected SheetWriter classes and their mappings internally here, without any of the outside code being affected, nor needing to change.

[image]

Here are the code listing for the "writers" package components

The publicly useable part (the API) of the package -

```java
public interface WritableModel { }

public interface SheetWriter<M extends WritableModel> {
    Sheet write(M model);
}

public class Writers {
    private static final Map<Class<? extends WritableModel>,
                             WriterFactory<? extends WritableModel, ? extends SheetWriter<?>>> factories;

    static {
        factories = new HashMap<>();
        factories.put(Model1.class, new Model1WriterFactory());
        factories.put(Model2.class, new Model2WriterFactory());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <M extends WritableModel> SheetWriter<M> writerFor(M model) {
        Class<? extends WritableModel> modelClass = model.getClass();
        if (isNull(factories.get(modelClass))) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No Writer for the provided Model's type (" + modelClass + ")");
        }
        return (SheetWriter<M>) factories.get(modelClass).get();
    }
}
```

and the internal (package-protected) implementation of needed factories and strategies -

```java
interface WriterFactory<M extends WritableModel, W extends SheetWriter<M>> {
    W get();
}

class Model1WriterFactory implements WriterFactory<Model1, Model1Writer> {
    @Override
    public Model1Writer get() {
        return new Model1Writer();
    }
}

class Model1Writer implements SheetWriter<Model1> {

    private final Sheet outputSheet;

    public Model1Writer() {
        this.outputSheet = new Sheet();
    }   

    @Override
    public Sheet write(Model1 model) {
        //this is your model-dependent logic of how Sheet is filled from the model
        outputSheet.addRow(model.getName() + ": has " + model.getChildCount() + " children");
        return outputSheet;
    }
}

class Model2WriterFactory implements WriterFactory<Model2, Model2Writer> {
    @Override
    public Model2Writer get() {
        return new Model2Writer();
    }
}

class Model2Writer implements SheetWriter<Model2&t; {
    private final Sheet outputSheet;

    public Model2Writer() {
        this.outputSheet = new Sheet();
    }

    @Override
    public Sheet write(Model2 model) {
        //this is your model-dependent logic of how Sheet is filled from the model
        outputSheet.addRow(model.toString());
        return outputSheet;
    }
}
```

The implementations above allow us to extend the Sheet writing logic for a new (i.e., Model3) class by mostly adding only new code - and just slightly modifying the Writers class static factories map - by adding a new entry.

As a limitation of this design though - both concrete `SheetWriter` classes only accept their corresponding model instances, to maintain a good narrow focus of responsibility. If however, you'd want to use and write info about Model2 instances contained inside Model1 into the first sheet - then you can do that in  `Model1Writer` since you have those Model2 objecst contained, but not the other way around - eg if in Model2 Sheet you need also to write some info coming from Model1 objects of the response, then currently by this design that is not available. If this is really necessary, you could fix this - by passing the whole "context" eg by making the `SheetWriter` interface method to also require entire `Response` as 2nd parameter:

```java
public interface SheetWriter<M extends WritableModel> {
    Sheet write(M model, Response response);
}
```

For completeness of the prior code, the following listing also includes my "dummy" implementations for `Response`, `Model1`, `Model2`, `Workbook` and `Sheet`

```java
public class Response {
    private final List<Model1> models = new ArrayList<>();

    public Response(Model1... models) {
        this.models.addAll(asList(models));
    }

    public List<Model1> getModels() {
        return new ArrayList<>(models);
    }

    public void addModel(Model1 model) {
        models.add(model);
    }
}

@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Model1 implements WritableModel {

    private final String name;
    private final List<Model2> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " = " + this.name;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Model2> children) {
        this.children.clear();
        this.children.addAll(children);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getChildCount() {
        return children.size();
    }

    public List<Model2> getChildren() {
        return new ArrayList<>(this.children);
    }
}

@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Model2 implements WritableModel {

    private final String title;
    private final int value;

    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + this.title + " (" + this.value + ")";
    }
}

@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Workbook {

    private final List<Sheet> sheets;

    public Workbook(Sheet... sheets) {
        this.sheets = asList(sheets);
    }

    public List<Sheet> getSheets() {
        return sheets;
    }
}

public class Sheet {

    private List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRow(String value) {
        rows.add(value);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.join("\n", rows);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: updated the answer with part below, to include data models delegation as well**

Here is the link to my repository containing the whole implementation:

https://github.com/Ristox/sheetwriters

The code of data models has been updated to implement delegation - our own `data` package defines custom model classes which both "wrap" the original, non-modifiable / non-extendable model classes from `blackbox` package, as follows:

```java
package org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.blackbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *  Pretend this is a "black-box" library class eg you know the public interface, but cannot change it
 */
public final class ExternalModel1 {
  private final String name;
  private final List<ExternalModel2> children = new ArrayList<>();

  public ExternalModel1(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " = " + this.name;
  }

  public void setChildren(List<ExternalModel2> children) {
    this.children.clear();
    this.children.addAll(children);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getChildCount() {
    return children.size();
  }

  public List<ExternalModel2> getChildren() {
    return new ArrayList<>(this.children);
  }
}



package org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.blackbox;

/**
 *  Pretend this is a "black-box" library class eg you know the public interface, but cannot change it
 */
public final class ExternalModel2 {
  private final String title;
  private final int value;

  public ExternalModel2(String title, int value) {
    this.title = title;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + this.title + " (" + this.value + ")";
  }
}


package org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.data;

import java.util.List;
import org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.blackbox.ExternalModel1;
import org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.writers.WritableModel;

public class Model1 implements WritableModel {

    private final ExternalModel1 delegate;

    public Model1(String name) {
        delegate = new ExternalModel1(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.delegate.toString();
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Model2> children) {
        this.delegate.setChildren(Model2.toDelegates(children));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.delegate.getName();
    }

    public int getChildCount() {
        return this.delegate.getChildCount();
    }

    public List<Model2> getChildren() {
        return Model2.wrapAll(this.delegate.getChildren());
    }
}

package org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.data;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.List;
import org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.blackbox.ExternalModel2;
import org.example.workbook.sheetwriters.writers.WritableModel;

public class Model2 implements WritableModel {

    public static Model2 wrap(ExternalModel2 externalModel) {
        return new Model2(externalModel);
    }

    public static List<Model2> wrapAll(List<ExternalModel2> externalModels) {
        return externalModels.stream().map(Model2::wrap).collect(toList());
    }

    public static List<ExternalModel2> toDelegates(List<Model2> model2List) {
        return model2List.stream().map(Model2::toDelegate).collect(toList());
    }

    private final ExternalModel2 delegate;

    public Model2(String title, int value) {
        this.delegate = new ExternalModel2(title, value);
    }

    private Model2(ExternalModel2 delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.delegate.toString();
    }

    public ExternalModel2 toDelegate() {
        return this.delegate;
    }
}
```

If the original "black-box" model classes have a big public interface, then it might seem tedious to repeat + delegate the entire interface manually. In this case, you might want to look into compile-time pre-processors and using their boilerplate annotations such as [Lombok's @Delegate](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate). It has its ups and downs, but if used thoughtfully and consciously, should be able to achieve the entire necessary delegation with considerably less boilerplate code.

Comment: Hi Risto Uibo, This solution is perfect. But I have one problem, Model 1 and Model 2 can not implement anything, they are included as part of external library. I have only plain Model 1 and Model with simple attributes.

Comment: Ok, in this case what we can do is create delegate classes for both Model1 and Model2 classes. These wrap around original instances - representing exactly the same information. You can also use inheritance, but I'd prefer delegate more. Then the control of "flagging" your model types as `WritableModel` implementations is back in your hands.

A less favourable alternative would be to loose the flagging interface and use `Object` instead everywhere, but it is IMHO not a good design, since it will allow arbitrary types of objects and beats the main purpose of the polymorphic design.

Comment: @achjavaoracle - the answer is now updated to include data model delegation in the proposed solution. Also, added link to github repository containing the full code.